# Array Data is not printing in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, runtime-error

This is my component that contains array data and data is printing in console but its not print in view

```
const optionView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.OptionView}>
        {allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]?.options.map((option, index) => {
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={() => {}}
            style={styles.ButtonView}>
            <View style={{}}>
              <Text style={styles.optionText}>{option}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>;
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: what do you mean print in view ?

Comment: The callback of your `.map` doesn't return anything ... either just replace the curly braces with parenthesis or add a `return ( ... )`  around your `<TouchableOpacity>` like you have done on the top. And get rid of that unecessary `;`

Comment: ThankYou very much, Now its working fine, Your support is appreciable.